# I have a nested table with 3 columns named marks1, marks2 and marks3. how to get distinct values of marks1 in another nested table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Have a nested table with 3 columns named marks1, marks2 and marks3. how to get distinct values of marks1 in another nested table?

### **nested_table1**

```
marks1   marks2   marks3
25       26       28
22       56       78
25       45       65
23       56       40
```

---

### **nested_table2**

```
distict_marks1
25
22
23
```

Comment: Are you talking about a "real" [nested table](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#i2153200) in Oracle? Please [edit] your question and add the **complete** `create table` statement for the main table and the nested table.

Answer (score 0):

Put `DISTINCT` or `UNIQUE` keyword after `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT marks1 
FROM nested_table1;
```

or

```
SELECT UNIQUE marks1 
FROM nested_table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into nested_table2  distinct_marks1
select distinct marks1 from nested_table1;

select distinct_marks1 from nested_table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct marks1
bulk collect into nested_table2 --nested_table2 should be of schema level typ
from table(nested_table1);
```

eg:id_arr is schema level nested table type

```
DECLARE
a id_arr :=id_arr(1,2,3,4,5,1,2);
b id_arr;
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_VALUE
  BULK COLLECT INTO b
  FROM TABLE(a);
  FOR i IN b.first..b.last LOOP
    PL(b(i));
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

Comment: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function

Comment: Then why do you use it like a function?

Comment: clause :- (grammar) an expression including a subject and predicate but not constituting a complete sentence ..go google for your unnecessary doubts

Comment: The point is that putting a column in parentheses makes no sense. `distinct        (marks1)` is absolutely the same as `distinct marks1`. Would you write `select (marks1)`? If not, then why do you enclose the column in parentheses when using `distinct`?

Comment: Oracle allows both convention which means both are acceptable,meaningful and correct..Reason why I wrote it like that...is old bad habbit :-(..I have changed by the way